# Step by step guide to setup a DHCP server / client configuration in VirtualBox

Tags: networking, server, dhcp, virtualbox-networking, dhcpd

I'm trying to implement DHCP on two VirtualBox machine, which both are running Ubuntu 16.10 (One as client, one as server) and the host is a Windows 10.

How do I go about doing this?

A step by step tutorial would be much appreciated as I am a beginner.

Answer (score 6):

First of all, we should make sure that our VMs have connectivity to the Internet, we are going to do that by enabling a NAT adapter on each machine (If it's not already enabled), also our machines should be sitting at the same network, so we will create a host-only network and add both machine to it by adding a new host-only adapter to each of them.

#### Create a host only network

In VirtualBox from `file` menu select `preferences` and in VirtualBox Preferences window, select Network, then host only networks. after all by clicking on `+` sign add a new host only network.

[image]

#### Add our machines to the same network

Now for both Ubuntu virtual machines, right click on each of them, select `settings`, go to network section. make sure `Adapter 1` is active and is attached to `Nat`, click on `Adapter 2`, check `Enable Network Adapter` and for `Attached to` select `Host-Only adapter`. click ok to save these settings.

[image]

#### Running DHCP Server

We are going to use `dnsmasq` as our DHCP Server, it's fairly small and is good enough for our purpose, so to install it run:

```
sudo apt-get install dnsmasq
```

Then we should enable dnsmasq DHCP functionality, before doing that lets take a look at or network interfaces by running:

```
ifconfig -a
```

we should get something similar to this:

[image]

`enp0s3` is or first adapter, do you remember the Nat interface? it's already has an IP (10.0.2.15), we don't have anything to do with this interface, we just created it to get Internet access if it was necessary for installing stuff, etc.

`enp0s8` is connected to our `vboxnet0` network which we just create it in first section, we should make this interface listing to DHCP request and response to them.

Now lets back to enabling DHCP server functionality for `dnsmas`, simply run this command:

```
sudo nano /etc/dnsmasq.conf
```

It will open `dnsmasq` configuration file in `nano` editor. there are some lines we should uncomment and add our configuration to these lines are:

```
interface=enp0s8
bind-interfaces
dhcp-range=192.168.100.10,192.168.100.20,24h
```

You can just paste them into this config file too, for `interface`, we should use `enp0s8`, we just talked about it right?

And `dhcp-range` is the range we want to assign to our requests from: `192.168.100.10` to `192.168.100.20` with the lease time of `24` hours.

Now we should give our `enp0s8` interface an IP address, e.g:

```
sudo ifconfig enp0s8 192.168.100.1
sudo ifconfig enp0s8 up
```

You can edit `interfaces` file and assign a static IP to this interface too.

After all we should start `dnsmasq` daemon:

```
sudo systemctl start dnsmasq.service
```

#### Client

Turn on your other Ubuntu machine, it should have network manager installed by default, and a connection to this network should already be there. the default method is to use DHCP, so you have to do nothing. just enable the new network, the name should be `Wired Connection 2`, and done, your interface will get an IP.

If you have a look at network information, you can see that this interface has an IP in the range that we setup in our DHCP Server:

[image]

You can also run `sudo dhclient enp0s3`, to get a IP for enp0s3 interface.

Answer (score 0):

First install `dhcp server`

```
sudo apt install isc-dhcp-server
```

Then select Interface card on with will `dhcp server` work.

`sudo nano /etc/default/isc-dhcp-server`

```
# Defaults for isc-dhcp-server initscript
# sourced by /etc/init.d/isc-dhcp-server
# installed at /etc/default/isc-dhcp-server by the maintainer scripts

#
# This is a POSIX shell fragment
#

# Path to dhcpd's config file (default: /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf).
#DHCPD_CONF=/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf

# Path to dhcpd's PID file (default: /var/run/dhcpd.pid).
#DHCPD_PID=/var/run/dhcpd.pid

# Additional options to start dhcpd with.
#   Don't use options -cf or -pf here; use DHCPD_CONF/ DHCPD_PID instead
#OPTIONS=""

# On what interfaces should the DHCP server (dhcpd) serve DHCP requests?
#   Separate multiple interfaces with spaces, e.g. "eth0 eth1".
INTERFACES="eth0"
```

In this case nic is `eth0`

Configure Subnet

`sudo nano  /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf`

comment all and above put this

```
subnet 192.168.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
       range 192.168.0.xxx 192.168.0.xxx;
        option routers                  192.168.0.x;
        option subnet-mask              255.255.255.0;
        option broadcast-address        192.168.0.255;
        option domain-name-servers      xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;
        default-lease-time 86400;
        max-lease-time 86400;


}
```

Restart service

```
sudo service isc-dhcp-server restart
```

For client is enough to select car config via `dhcp`.

Try.