# setup test server ubuntu on virtualbox on window

Tags: virtualbox, webserver, static-ip

I am trying to setup a test web server
My machine is a windows 10
I installed virtualbox -> then ubuntu -> mysql -> apache2 -> php

I am able to test like this in my ubuntu http://localhost/info.php -> working

I am not sure how to connect from my windows box to my web server on ubuntu. Thanks so much for helping me

```
cat interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
#iface lo inet loopback
iface lo inet static
address 192.168.1.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1


*ifconfig
enp0s3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.2.15  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.2.255
        inet6 fe80::55d:fcc7:9636:c597  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:00:27:8d:b4:be  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 10205  bytes 10467155 (10.4 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 3596  bytes 442501 (442.5 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 464  bytes 63031 (63.0 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 464  bytes 63031 (63.0 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0*
```

Comment: Eaasiest way is to stop the virtual machine and use bridged networking. Your ubuntu server will then have an ip address on the same network as your windows host. You then either connect via ip or add your server to the windows host file `http://192.168.1.your_server_ip`

Comment: See also https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_bridged

Answer (score 2):

As your output indicates, you have only one interface which is set to use `NAT`.

To be able to send request from your host to your Ubuntu, you should create a `Host-only` network, and a new interface for your VM, then attach your VM to this network which your host is sitting on it too.

---

#### Create a host-only network:

In VirtualBox from `file` menu select `preferences` and in VirtualBox Preferences window, select Network, then host only networks.

After all by clicking on `+` plus sign add a new `host-only` network. it's name should be `vboxnet0`.

---

#### Run DHCP server

Then double click on it and go to `DHCP` tab to run a `DHCP Server` on this network, do your desired configuration as follow:

[image]

---

#### Create a new interface

Then you should add an interface to your Ubuntu VM and attach it to this network.

Do a right click on your Ubuntu VM, select `settings`, go to `network section`.  Click on `Adapter 2`, check `Enable Network Adapter` and for `Attached to` select `Host-Only adapter`.

[image]

After all click `ok` to save these settings.

Now when you turn this VM on, you have a new interface, something like: `enp0s9` which it should have an IP between 192.168.56.10 to 100, it should be 192.168.56.10. use `ip a` or `ifconfig -a` to find it out.

---

#### Config Apache

Now make apache to listen to this IP by changing apache configuration file to something like:

```
Listen 0.0.0.0:80
```

Or exactly your own IP, like:

```
Listen 192.168.56.10:80
```

*Some part of this answer, and pictures are from my other answer related to VirtualBox from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/906151/step-by-step-guide-to-setup-a-dhcp-server-client-configuartion-in-virtualbox/906178#906178).*