# Getting an IP address with Ubuntu client from Windows Server 2016 DHCP in VirtualBox

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox, windows, dhcp

So we have a task in university which is basically about 3 parts.
We have a Ubuntu 18.04 client and a Windows 2016 Server, both in VirtualBox.
We should do, so that:

1. The Ubuntu client should get an IP address AUTOMATICALLY from the Windows 2016 Server's DHCP. ((The Win2016 Server DHCP is already configured, but Ubuntu does not connect to it somehow)). Our Ubuntu has 2 IPs currently, one starting with 127.x.x.x and one starting with 10.x.x.x. So it is not good (our DHCP is giving out addressess between 192.168.1.65 and 192.168.1.70)
2. There is also an IIS installed on the Win2016 server. Typing in the server's IP in the browser (192.168.1.1), it should bring up a "webpage". This does not work on Ubuntu neither, but we can access the webpage when we type in the server's IP on the server. So it SHOULD work.
3. We should install ProFTP on Ubuntu and connect with it to the server's FTP domain. [[This task should work easily after the two former tasks are done. I THINK. So I do not need help with the 3rd task I THINK.]]

Any help on how to do this is welcome, since we did not learn this and it would be a really big help since I am not familiar with linux-based OP systems.
Have a nice day!

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen here is the ping :)

Comment: Hello Noxter can we see if we can resolve this issue? I am waiting and have about 10mins!

Answer (score 0):

Let provide an arrangement that should work. For questions (2) and (3) that has to do with the network set which if the steps I will show goes well then those should work.

Step 1: Set `Host-Only` network on Virtualbox:

1. Setup Host-Only Network for both machines. Open the file menu and click on `Host Network Manager`

   [image]
2. Create the Host-Only network by clicking `create` button:

   [image]
3. Now on both machines do the following:

   - Set click on the machine then settings and setup both NAT for first adapter then Host-Only for second adapter as seen in the images below:

   [image]

   [image]

Now I have not tested this and I have adapted it from an answer given [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/906178/459561). I am assuming like you said the Windows DHCP Server has been setup so following that reference simply turning on the Ubuntu client should have it connect to the Windows server and get an IP from there. Enable that network on Ubuntu machine.

Comment: Thank you. We will check it soon and I will give you a feedback once we are done. Fingers crossed! :) So should we set this up on the Win server as well or only on the Ubuntu client?

Comment: It's for both machines!

Comment: Hey. We tried it now. We added a host only network in VB (with default settings) and then we added a host only adapter card for both the ubuntu client and the win server as well. We try to ping the server's IP and it doesnt work. We are not getting an IP from the server. We did everything the way the picture show us. Do you have any idea we should try out? A guy told us that the ubuntu client only need an "inner" card and it should work automatically while the server needs a NAT AND AN INNER CARD to work. It doesnt work either. :(

Answer (score 0):

Is you windows DHCP server Authorized ? I understand you said it's configured but configure and Authorized are two different things if its not authorized it will not serve IP address, which might be happing in your case (1)

if DHCP server is already authorized , lets look somewhat more :)

look at networking :

check by assigning static ip address to the new interfaces you created and try to ping from self first, later try to ping ubuntu from windows and windows from ubuntu. what is the output of all let us know. 
           if its not pinging go one step ahead and try tracert X.x.x.x from the windows box Where X.x.x.x is the ip of the ubuntu box.
           try to open default browser on ubuntu and type ip address of the windows box see that IIS is reachable.

Waiting for your reply